# Предложение, состоящее из одной только грамматической основы (подлежащее+сказуемое) считается полным?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, основа

Утром спокойно над промыслами взошло яркое солнце, но шторм не ослабевал.
Во второй части ССП "шторм не ослабевал" - полное предложение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Шторм не ослабевал*** – это полное предложение. Оно состоит из одной основы, поэтому называется нераспростаненным.

Информация

**Нераспростаненные предложения** не содержат второстепенных членов https://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=3563e989-9a6f-4301-873b-7ca4d42b59e3

**Неполные предложения** https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya225-nepolnyepredlogeniya.html

Неполными называются предложения, в которых пропущен какой-либо необходимый по смыслу и структуре член предложения (главный или второстепенный). Неполными могут быть двусоставные и односоставные, распространенные и нераспространенные предложения. Возможность пропуска членов предложения объясняется тем, что они ясны **из контекста, из ситуации речи или из структуры самого предложения**. Таким образом, смысл неполных предложений воспринимается с опорой **на ситуацию или контекст.**